# Is there something like master page in desktop aplications?

Tags: winforms, master-pages

Can I have master form that will contain windows forms? Or even windows control?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: a form that will what? You're missing a verb there.

Comment: "contain" is missing word, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create a [Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx).  Also, all windows forms can contain controls, so you can by definition create a form that contains a control.

Answer (score 4):

For a form to contain other forms, you want MDI (as Zach Johnson already said). Setting the relevant form properties (IsMdiContainer / MdiChildren / MdiParent / etc) will get you the behaviour you want.

For something like a "master page for forms", you could try using [Visual Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz%28VS.80%29.aspx). First you define a basic "master" form layout, leaving space for the controls on the child forms. Then when you create new forms, be sure to select Add New-->Windows Forms-->Inherited Form, and Visual Studio will prompt you to select a parent form to inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with inheritance i suppose

Comment: Why the downvote? This is absolutely right. Visual inheritance, as pointed out by Matt Bishop, is a nice way to achieve an effect on Windows Forms very similar to that of master pages on ASP.NET.

Comment: I did not click it well... after that i try to vote it bu it said too old

Answer (score 0):

A winform application I work has a main form that is completely built in this manner.  It uses one Winform and everything displayed on it is a user control. All the displays are written as plugins and can be pulled into the applications menu and have their user control displayed.